# Наследование и переопределение констант c++

Tags: c++

Положим существует базовый класс юнита, содержащий константу здоровья. Т.к. все наследующие классы описывают разных юнитов, как можно переопределить константу с новыми значениями? Можно ли сделать полиморфизм для константы так сказать? )

Comment: покажите часть кода без  методов

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> как можно переопределить константу с новыми значениями?

Если просто попробовать создать в дочернем классе константу с тем же именем, то эффект будет как при переопределении невиртуального метода. Так что так делать не стоит.

> Можно ли сделать полиморфизм для константы так сказать?

Вместо константы делайте виртуальный метод и возвращайте из него нужное число.

Answer (score 1):

Например:

```
class Base {
    const int k;
public:
    Base(const int i) : k(i) {}
    virtual void print() const { std::cout << k << std::endl; }
};
class D1 : public Base {
public:
    D1(const int j) : Base(j) {}
};

class D2 : public D1 {
public:
    D2(const int j) : D1(j) {}
};
```

В итоге, каждый производный класс наследует свой  `Base`, и у каждого своя константа.